# React Custom Multi Select Not working with external array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-and-multi-select-non-native?file=index.js

In this multiselect mode, I want to show API data for my project, but its not showing that list. I have tried with same object key also. could you please help??

Code:

```
  let [arr, setArrList] = useState([])
 const getCollectionCentersList = () => {
      let obj = {
          pathology_id : param.pathology_id
      }
      labService.getCollectionCenterByLab(obj).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      let arr1 = res.Response.map(item => {
        return {
            'pathology_name' : item.pathology_name,
            'id' : item.id
        }
        })
        console.log(arr1)
        setArrList(arr1)
      }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err)
         alert(err.message)
      })
  }
 
  useEffect(getCollectionCentersList, [])
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
          <MultiSelect 
             label={'Collection Centers'}
             placeholder={'Select'}
             // options={['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5']}
              options={arr}
              values={values}
              onChange={handleOnChangeMultiSelect}
              disabled={false}
              required
               style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
             />
     </div>
```

Comment: why can't you create a local state for options and update the state once you receive the API response.

Comment: yes, I have done like that only..

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, pathology_name, pathology_id, pathology_code, address, phone_number, email_id, website, logo_name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.=> i got this error, when I useState.

Comment: are you getting this error while updating the state ? Could you please include all the changes in the shared link ?

Comment: https://react-select-and-multi-select-non-native-fwpmwa.stackblitz.io

Comment: here i have included my code..

Comment: shared link is not loading for me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-and-multi-select-non-native-fwpmwa?file=index.js    => please check this..

Comment: If the below approach is working, please accept it as answer.

Comment: sorry, still its not working, throwing same error.. i updated my changes in my question. can you please check once??

Comment: `return {  'name' : item.pathology_name, value:  item.pathology_name, 'id' : item.id }`   just an assumption

Answer (score 2):

try the below approach,

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Select from './Select/Select';
    import MultiSelect from './Select/MultiSelect'
    import './style.css';
    
    const App = () => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState()
      const [values, setValues] = useState([])
      let [arr, setArrList] = useState([])
      const tempArray = [{
          name: "test1",
          value : "hdjvjv",
          id: 1
      },{
          name: "test2",
          value : "hdjvvfve",
          id: 2
      }]
    
      // This code is incorrect, your array doesn't have 'pathology_name'
      // arr = arr.map(item => {
      //       return {
      //           'name' : item.pathology_name,
      //           'value' : item.id
      //       }
      //    })
    
         
    useEffect(()=> {
            setArrList(tempArray); // Update the state here
         }, []);
    
      console.log(arr) 
      const handleOnChangeSelect = (value, e) => {
        console.log('onChangeSelect', value)
        setValue(value)
      }
      const handleOnChangeMultiSelect = (values, e) => {
        console.log('onChangeMultiSelect', values)
        setValues(values)
      }
    
    
      return (
        <div style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}>
          <form>
            <Select 
              label={'Mode'}
              placeholder={'Choose mode'}
              // options={['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5']}
              options={arr}
              onChange={handleOnChangeSelect}
              disabled={false}
              required
              value={value}
            />
            <MultiSelect 
              label={'Mode'}
              placeholder={'Choose modes'}
              // options={['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5']}
              options={arr} // use state value here
              values={values}
              onChange={handleOnChangeMultiSelect}
              disabled={false}
              required
              style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Updated the code with respect to your changes.

```
const getCollectionCentersList = () => {
      setArrList([{
      name: "test12",
      value : "hdjvjv",
      id: 1
  },{
      name: "test2",
      value : "hdjvvfve",
      id: 2
  }])
  }
```